# Как изменить размер изображения?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Совсем не пойму, как изменить размер изображения и после загрузить его.

```
<?
$types_ext = array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/png');
$extension = array('jpeg','jpg','gif','png');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_FILES['file']['error'] != 0){
echo 'Вы не загрузили файл';
}elseif($_FILES['file']['size'] <5000 || $_FILES['file']['size']>50000000){
echo 'Размер изображения нам не подходит.';
}else{
preg_match('#\.([a-z]+)$#iu',$_FILES['file']['name'],$matches);
if(isset($matches[1])){
$matches[1] = mb_strToLower($matches[1]);
$temp = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$name = '/templates/default/img/'.date("Ymd_His").'img'.rand(100,999).'.png';
$width = 100;
$height = 100;
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = $temp;
if ($width_orig > $width) {
   $width_orig = $width;
} else {
   $height_orig = $height;
}
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = ImageCreateFromPNG(?);// Тут что надо поставить,чтоб не было ошибок?
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
imagepng($image_p,?);// а тут?
// Или нужно вообще по другому?
if(!in_array($matches[1],$extension)){
echo 'У вашего изображения неправильное расширение.';
}elseif(!in_array($temp['mime'],$types_ext)){
echo "Не подходит тип файла";
}elseif(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'.'.$name)){
echo 'Вы неправильно загрузили изображение.';
}else{
echo 'Ваше изображение загружено верно.';
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: [декомпозиция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) плюс [вот](http://hashcode.ru/questions/328228/php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=328231#328231) я еще банальщину писал.

> Тут что надо поставить,чтоб не было ошибок?

Путь к файлу, который `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`. Для определения типа нужно использовать 3й элемент вывода `getimagesize()`.

Comment: Я решил задачу,но спасибо..Просто сам принцип неправильно понял,оттого и не смог до этого решить задачу. Но все равно тебе спасибо)Чуть ниже сделаю ответ на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение.

```
<?
$types_ext = array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/png');
$extension = array('jpeg','jpg','gif','png');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_FILES['file']['error'] != 0){
echo 'Вы не загрузили файл';
}elseif($_FILES['file']['size'] <5000 || $_FILES['file']['size']>50000000){
echo 'Размер изображения нам не подходит.';
}else{
preg_match('#\.([a-z]+)$#iu',$_FILES['file']['name'],$matches);
if(isset($matches[1])){
$matches[1] = mb_strToLower($matches[1]);
$temp = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$name = '/templates/default/img/'.date("Ymd_His").'img'.rand(100,999).'.png';
$percent = 0.5; 
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = $temp;
$width = $width_orig*$percent;
$height = $height_orig*$percent;
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = ImageCreateFromPNG($tmp_name);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
imagepng($image_p,$tmp_name,0);
imagedestroy($image_p);
if(!in_array($matches[1],$extension)){
echo 'У вашего изображения неправильное расширение.';
}elseif(!in_array($temp['mime'],$types_ext)){
echo "Не подходит тип файла";
}elseif(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'.'.$name)){
echo 'Вы неправильно загрузили изображение.';
}else{
echo 'Ваше изображение загружено верно.';
}
}
}
}
?>
```